# I have 2 datepickers and I want to select the 2 dates that are overlapping, in between or outside this date

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, datepicker

I'm making a parking reservation system with a starttime/date **and** endtime/date. 
You can't reserve the same spot at the same time, because it is already taken by another car.

There are three options:
- overlapping times/dates
- between the times/dates
- around the times/dates

example of database:

```
  STARTTIME            | ENDTIME                
  2014-11-14 13:00:00  | 2014-11-16  14:00:00
```

I want to search in the database all dates that are unavailable.
For example:

A **new** booking (AROUND excisting dates) by user input,

```
  STARTTIM             | ENDTIME            
  2014-11-13 10:00:00  | 2014-11-17  16:00:00
```

If the new booking in any way is overlapping the excisting booking, the query should output all dates that are unavailable

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the logic that you want:

```
select t.*
from table t
where p.starttime < @EndTime and p.EndTime > @StartTime;
```

where `@StartTime` and `@EndTime` are variables with the user input.  The idea is that two periods overlap if one starts before the other ends, and the first ends after the other starts.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, but this code only covers the total overlap, not if one of the two is inbetween.

Comment: @Joost . . . The text had the right logic, but the code was wrong.  I fixed the code to match the description.